# How to create custom object in ODOO?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, erp

Are there any way to create some new model after onchange triggered?

For example, I want to create my custom report object after the state of quotation is changed to sale order.

Comment: What do you mean with "to create custom report object"?

Comment: It means "new" model that I created in my module. I want to add that after onchange of state of quotation is triggered.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would you please share your efforts in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved that by trying to override action_confirm method of sale.order and it's worked!

```
class sale_order(models.Model) :
     _inherit = 'sale.order'
     job_container = fields.One2many('job.container','order')

     @api.multi
     def action_confirm(self):
            super(sale_order, self).action_confirm()
            self.env['job.container'].create({
                'order': self.id
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new instance of a model with the following code <del>inside `sales.order` inside a method with the decorator `@api.onchange('state')`</del>:

```
   report_model = self.env['my.custom.report.object']
   new_report_object = report_model.create({
         'report_message': 'Quotation changed state to Sales Order'
   })
```

Comment: I tried that way, however, nothing is called, but now I got the solution.

Comment: You are right, I did not execute the code to test. As the state is changed in the backend / and not in the view - the onchange function is not triggered. I changed my answer to not misslead other users. Thank you!